# PHP GD text wraps differently in browser than in created file

Tags: php, gd

My text wraps great when its rendered in the browser:
http://www.morriescontests.com/index.php/view/page/image

But when the same code simply creates and saves a new file it doesn't:
http://www.morriescontests.com/images/uploads/32-142.png

This obviously makes me incredibly sad :(

They are separate scripts, one was for testing. The script that doesn't wrap correctly only has one difference, no headers are sent (obvi). I'm using the imgpng($image, $filename) function.

both scripts are on the same server, here is the last line of code:

```
// create image
header("Content-type: image/png"); // this is omitted from the incorrect wrapping script
// send to browser
imagepng($img); // this is omitted from the incorrect wrapping script
// save to file
$filepath = "the/path/image.png";
imagepng($img, $filepath);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Have you tried sending out the proper headers?  Also, can you post some code, so we can see what you're doing?  And I'm assuming that these are on the same server, right?  So you aren't working with different PHP engines, or using different versions of the GD library.  GD 1 uses different measurements for text than GD2

Comment: i added the bottom code, i'm not sending out any headers for the saving script.

Comment: That's all standard stuff.  I was looking at the generation of the bounding box for the image.  Not how you're sending it.  That's where I think the issue lies.  Also, is this on the same server as the other script?

Comment: Its very bizarre, the "good" script saves images correctly, if you see the answer below Sabeen ran it by changing the URL parameter's user_id and id. The file naming convention is user_id-id.png. The overwritten file is now correct looking. I don't get it. It must have something to do with the headers, but if i set the headers in my actual live script it throws an error because its not supposed to display the image, just create it.

Comment: I fixed it. When I copied over my code to the official file I forgot to remove the function I wrote to process the GET variables. 
    foreach($_GET as $varname => $value)
    {
      $$varname = $value;
    }
Even though I was changing those values lower down in the script, for reasons unknown to me, this loop was messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

So did some investigation, you are using the path

http://www.morriescontests.com/billboardImage.php?caption=LONG%20STRING%20WRAP%20TEST,%20HMMMM%20I%20WONDER%20WHAT%20WILL%20HAPPEN%20NOW?&first_name=Andrew&last_initial=S.&city=Red%20Bank&user_id=32&id=128

to generate the image but the image you were looking at was 32-142.png

so i changed the url to

http://www.morriescontests.com/billboardImage.php?caption=LONG%20STRING%20WRAP%20TEST,%20HMMMM%20I%20WONDER%20WHAT%20WILL%20HAPPEN%20NOW?&first_name=Andrew&last_initial=S.&city=Red%20Bank&user_id=32&id=142

notice the id=142 and it works ok now. So it seems like the 32-142.png image you were seeing was created previously :)

Comment: billboarImage.php is just a test script. It uses GET variables to generate the image. You can change those id's to any number and get the same results.  The actual script, which is for purely saving, grabs those ID's from a database, and for some reason doesn't wrap the text the same even though code is identical except for the output of the image. So essentially what you did was just overwrite the incorrect image made by the bad script with a correct image made by the good one. I think it has something to do with the headers because that is the only difference between the two.